# User profile inputs will not save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On a page a user is prompted to enter their location, twitter screenname, Facebook URL, and LinkedIn URL. What is missing that is not allowing it to be saved in the database?

User model (user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chatpost, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token
    attr_accessor :twitter_id, :facebook, :linkedin, :location

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :unless => lambda{ |user| user.password.blank? }

  # Convert user's name to friendly url format
  def slug
    name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")  
  end

  # Change default param for user from id to id-name for friendly urls.
  # When finding in DB, Rails auto calls .to_i on param, which tosses
  # name and doesn't cause any problems in locating user.
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{slug}"
  end

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end


  private
    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Users controller (users_controller.rb):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
    skip_before_filter :require_login, :only => [:new, :create]

  def index
        @user
    end

    def show
    # TODO: Redirect to canonical lins if slugs change
  # see: http://code-worrier.com/blog/custom-slugs-in-rails/
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      #redirect if we are already signed in
    if signed_in?
    flash[:notice] = "Already signed in"
    redirect_to root_path
    end
    #create a new variable to hold User params
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
    #Make the first user created a super user
    if User.count == 0
      @user[:super_user] = true
    else
      @user[:super_user] = false
    end
    if @user.save
            sign_in @user
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to LivePost!"
            redirect_to chatlogs_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user].permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :twitter_id, :facebook, :linkedin, :location))
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        User.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "User deleted."
        redirect_to root_path
    end



    private

    def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :twitter_id, :facebook, :linkedin, :location)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
            store_location
            redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
        end
    end

    def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Users helper (users_helper.rb):

```
module UsersHelper
  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user (see: http://gravatar.com/)
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar"
  end

  def twitter_for(user)
    user.twitter_id ? "https://www.twitter.com/#{user.twitter_id}" : ""
  end

  def facebook_for(user)
    #{user.facebook}
  end

  def linkedin_for(user)
      #{user.linkedin}
  end
end
```

User profile edit (views/users/edit.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit profile') %>
<div class="showuser">
  <row>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 6%;">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-left: 10px;">
        <div class="panel panel-body">
          <h3 class="form-signin-heading" align="center"><b><%= @user.name.titleize %>'s profile</b></h3>
          <%= form_for @user, class: "form-signin" do |f| %>
          <%= form_tag :action => 'update', :id => @user %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
          <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">Email</span></div>
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", disabled: true, style: "color: #999;" %>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    General User Information
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">Name</span></div>
                  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your name" %>
                  <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">Location</span></div>
                  <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your location" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    Avatar
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div>
                    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">Change avatar</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    Social Media
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">Twitter</span></div>
                  <%= f.text_field :twitter_id, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Twitter username" %>
                  <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">Facebook</span></div>
                  <%= f.text_field :facebook, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Facebook profile URL" %>
                  <div align="left"><span class="label label-default">LinkedIn</span></div>
                  <%= f.text_field :linkedin, class: "form-control", placeholder: "LinkedIn profile URL" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                    Password
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Confirm password" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div align="center">
              <%= link_to "Cancel", @user, style: "margin-right: 50px;" %>
              <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </row>
</div>
```

I've been somewhat stuck on this either not finding clear answers or not sure what to do (for example use Self). I've tried to solve this one for awhile and feel I'm missing something obvious but can't quite figure out what it is. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm still very much new to Ruby and RoR.

Edit: Rails server:

```
Started PATCH "/users/1-test" for 209.240.97.186 at 2013-12-24 14:43:38 +0000                                                                   
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML                                                                                                    
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YemNvIfdYxnChL5tsQxVXNxHLUHIOPeDJ45tHTiyN5s=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Test Addington", "location"=
>"California", "twitter_id"=>"", "facebook"=>"", "linkedin"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Up
date", "id"=>"1-test"}                                                                                                                          
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b6b3e86b6a7d3b77641f32d72d7f68b035944cac' LIMIT 1          
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1-test"]]                                           
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction                                                                                                                   
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('email@test.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1      
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["name", "Test Addington"], ["updated_at", Tue, 24 Dec 2
013 14:43:38 UTC +00:00]]                                                                                                                       
   (50.8ms)  commit transaction                                                                                                                 
Redirected to http://kingswood-rails-1-64062.euw1.actionbox.io:3000/users/1-test-addington                                                      
Completed 302 Found in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 52.0ms)                                                                                              


Started GET "/users/1-test-addington" for 209.240.97.186 at 2013-12-24 14:43:38 +0000                                                           
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML                                                                                                      
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1-test-addington"}                                                                                                        
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b6b3e86b6a7d3b77641f32d72d7f68b035944cac' LIMIT 1          
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1-test-addington"]]                                 
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)                                                                               
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)                                                                                                       
  Rendered layouts/_sidemenu.html.erb (0.7ms)                                                                                                   
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)                                                                                             
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)                                                                                                     
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 22.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: try to update with ! sign so it will show the error why they are not getting saved

Comment: I've added what the server shows when entering California directly from the view.

Comment: @NitinJ, pardon my ignorance but update what in particular? Are you referring to something I do in rails console?

Comment: @harrisongill why do you think this is not saving the record?  Your log indicates it _is_ saving and redirecting back to the user page.

Comment: @Donovan when I go into console and do User.first after the save its not there. It's saving the username and password fields, but nothing else.

Comment: What are you expecting to be saved?  The params for `twitter_id`, `facebook`, and `linked_in` are blank -- or is that the problem?

Comment: Well then it looks like I've made a bit of a stupid mistake. Yep, that is exactly the problem @Donovan.

Comment: @Donovan and @NitinJ - I think it has something to do with the way `def update` and `def user_params` is written in the controller. I could definitely use some advice, I'm not 100% sure what I did here.

Answer (score 1):

your params are coming blank thats why value is not getting saved

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YemNvIfdYxnChL5tsQxVXNxHLUHIOPeDJ45tHTiyN5s=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Test Addington", "location"=
>"California", "twitter_id"=>"", "facebook"=>"", "linkedin"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Up
date", "id"=>"1-test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based upon the comments you've made, this may be your problem...

In your `update` method, you're not using the `user_params` method you've already created for this purpose, and the params you are using seem a bit *strange* to me even though they don't seem to be generating any errors.

So, my suggestion would be to use the following in your `update` method:

```
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Donovan, that is definitely a step in the right direction because we are now getting nil values in the console. And there is quite some strange stuff I'm still figuring out especially as there have been changes since I last worked on the project. This however definitely makes the code much clearer and is a step in the right direction.

Comment: tried a couple of things with the form as well as in the controller (trying to make sure it saves) and now we can't get anything other than nil coming out of the console. The update method matches your suggestion.